# Fetch data from viewModel in fragment only once

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, fragment, viewmodel

I need to fetch data only once and avoid fetching it when screen is rotated.

MyFragment:

```
private var _binding: FragmentTopArticlesBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentTopArticlesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        getTopArticles()

        return binding.root
    }
```

Function for observing state :

```
private fun getTopArticles() {
        var sortedList = emptyList<Article>()
        val adapter = ArticleAdapter(
            onArticleClicked = { title ->
                Toast.makeText(context, title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        )
        binding.recyclerViewTop.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        binding.recyclerViewTop.adapter = adapter

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.stateUI.collect { it ->
                when (it) {
                    is StateUI.Success -> {
                        it.articles.collect { articles ->
                            if (articles.isNotEmpty()) {
                                observeArticles(sharedViewModel, articles, adapter)
```

Function for fetching data:

```
private suspend fun observeArticles(
            sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
            articles: List<Article>,
            adapter: ArticleAdapter
        ) {
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            sharedViewModel.sortState.collect { sortState ->
                val sortedList = when (sortState) {
                    SortOrderState.Ascending -> {
                        sharedViewModel.sortArticles(articles)
                    }
                    SortOrderState.Descening -> {
                        sharedViewModel.sortArticles(articles)
    
                    }
    
                }
                adapter.submitList(sortedList)
    
                binding.recyclerViewTop.postDelayed({
                    binding.recyclerViewTop.scrollToPosition(0)
                }, 1000)
            }
        }
```

My task is to fetch and sort data on 2 fragments when user click on menu item sort (asc or desc). Problem is when im rotating screen these functions fetch data but i want to do it only once when i come first time in Fragment.

I removed this line of code:

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Because I wouldn't be able to use scrollToPosition.

**Edit:**

ViewModel:

```
private val _cacheArticle = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Article>())
    val cacheArticle = _cacheArticle.asStateFlow()


    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            if(cacheArticle.value.isEmpty()){
                val observeTopArticles = articleRepository.getTopArticles()
                _cacheArticle.value = observeTopArticles
                _stateUI.value = StateUI.Success(articles = observeTopArticles)
                Log.d(TAG, ": PULL")
            } else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, ": CACHE1")
                _stateUI.value = StateUI.Success(articles = _cacheArticle.value)
            }

        }
```

Comment: Post code of the view model/how are you getting the data. You should not use flow if you want get data only once. Small hack could be calling cancel after receving the first data.

Comment: I removed all flows but stil fetching data from api, tried with some local stateFlow but still it wont store data and use it once when i fetch it from api

Comment: I just re-read your problem. You don't want data fetched on rotation. You are using ViewModel. it won't. ViewModel survives the configuration changes.

Comment: So it is ok to use viewModel without cacheArticle ?
observeTopArticles fetch data from api so i think it still fetch data when i rotate screen.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. The code you have there, it will not re-fetch it on rotation. ViewModels `init` will be called only once - that is if you are creating the `viewModel` correctly.

Comment: If i remove cacheArticle and just use observe is that still good ? Thanks for answering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248979/discussion-between-equlo-and-thelibrarian).

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch data in Fragment like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
        viewModel.fetchData()
}
```

After screen rotation and fragment re-creation `savedInstanceState` will not be null, so the method will only be called once when the fragment is created for the first time.